# Can't find out my url in Jboss server

Tags: jboss

As i am deployed Rest.ear file in the \jboss-eap-7.0\standalone folder.And .ear file is also deployed successfully, checked the server http://localhost:8080 is Application Platform is running,but, try to run my application http://localhost:8080/Rest , it's showing -(404 - Not Found) Error.

Could you please help me,how to find out my url in jboss server (or) we need to configure any other file. Thanks

Comment: You can check your Deployments and their Paths in the Admin Console of Jboss.
Goto `http://localhost:9990` log in as admin. Under Deployments check your EAR select the `untertow` element of the right component and it will show you the Context-Root of the deployment.

Comment: @Schlangguru ,, as per request i runned http://localhost:9990. Please refer below message is displaying.
_____________________________

However you have not yet added any users to be able to access the admin console.

To add a new user execute the add-user.sh script within the bin folder of your JBoss EAP 7 installation and enter the requested information.

By default the realm name used by JBoss EAP is "ManagementRealm" this is already selected by default.

After you have added the user follow this link to Try Again.

________________________________

Comment: Maybe https://serverfault.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: The message says everything. Run the add-user script and log in into the admin console.

Comment: @Schlangguru: don't known how to add my details in add-user script.So please tell any other solution for resolve this.

Comment: Just run the script. Is will ask you for all the details

Comment: @Schlangguru: No couldn't work, Alternate any other idea's

Answer (score 0):

Once you deploy the application, in your local environment. Open the location inside(eg:\Serveur\jboss\4.2.2.GA\server.) where your .ear file has been created. Open META-INF folder and you will find application.xml. Here whatever is mentioned within the tags MyApplication is your application path.

Your final url would be:
localhost:8080/MyApplication